# Got Ajax to submit form data, but won't do it for a textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I got an Ajax form working for the most part, but it only submits data from the input tags.  In my MySql database, both of the input forms will submit correctly, but my textarea will fill in as "undefined".

HTML:

```
<div id="contact_form">
  <form name="contact" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>

      <input title="name" label="Name" type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label>

      <input title="email" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />

      <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>

      <textarea type="text"  name="request" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" title="request" class="text-input"></textarea>

      <label class="error" for="request" id="request_error">This field is required.</label>

        <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('.error').hide();
  $('input.text-input').css({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
  $('input.text-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFDDAA"});
  });
  $('input.text-input').blur(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
  });

  $(".button").click(function() {
        // validate and process form
        // first hide any error messages
    $('.error').hide();

      var name = $("input#name").val();
        if (name == "") {
      $("label#name_error").show();
      $("input#name").focus();
      return false;
    }
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        if (email == "") {
      $("label#email_error").show();
      $("input#email").focus();
      return false;
    }
        var request = $("textarea#request").val();
        if (request == "") {
      $("label#request_error").show();
      $("textarea#request").focus();
      return false;
    }

        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&request=' + request;
        //alert (dataString);return false;

        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "bin/process.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
        });
      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
runOnLoad(function(){
  $("input#name").select().focus();
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $request=$_POST['request']; 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("form") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ajaxform` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$request')") or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

`var request = $("textarea#request").val();`

You don't have the `id` "request" on the `textarea`.

To fix, do one of the following:

1. `var request = $("textarea.text-input").val();`
2. `<textarea type="text" id="request" name="request" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" title="request" class="text-input"></textarea>`

Answer (score 2):

Textarea had no **id="request"**

```
<textarea type="text"  name="request" maxlength="1000" cols="25"
   rows="6" title="request" class="text-input"></textarea>

$("textarea#request").val();
```

Add the id for the Field or try this

```
$("textarea[name='request']").val();
```